# DbUp wants to run previously run scripts

Tags: c#, dbup

```
             IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.Development.json", true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables() // Overwrite with any environment variables, e.g., from Azure environments.
                .Build();

           var upgrader =
                DeployChanges.To
                    .SqlDatabase(connectionString)
                    .WithScriptsEmbeddedInAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), s => !s.Contains(TestDataScriptsFolderName), 
                    new DbUp.Engine.SqlScriptOptions
                    {
                        ScriptType = DbUp.Support.ScriptType.RunOnce,
                        RunGroupOrder = 1
                    })
                    .LogToConsole();

            if (args.Any(a => a.Contains("IncludeTestData")) || config.GetValue<bool>("IncludeTestData"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Test data scripts will be executed as part of the upgrade.");

                upgrader.WithScriptsEmbeddedInAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), s => s.Contains(TestDataScriptsFolderName),
                    new DbUp.Engine.SqlScriptOptions
                    {
                        //ScriptType = DbUp.Support.ScriptType.RunAlways, 
                        RunGroupOrder = 2
                    })
                    .LogToConsole();
            }

            DbUp.Engine.UpgradeEngine u = upgrader.Build();

            List<DbUp.Engine.SqlScript> allScripts = u.GetDiscoveredScripts();
            // 52 -- all of them

            List<string> executedScripts = u.GetExecutedScripts();
            // 543 -- because the test data scripts (which are idempotent) were run at every deployment.

            List<DbUp.Engine.SqlScript> todoScripts = u.GetScriptsToExecute();
            // All 52! It should be 0 because all scripts have been run.

            bool ug = u.IsUpgradeRequired();

            Console.WriteLine(allScripts.Any(z => z.Name.EndsWith("T20200518T1023_InitialTestData.sql")));
            Console.WriteLine(executedScripts.Any(z => z.EndsWith("T20200518T1023_InitialTestData.sql")));
            Console.WriteLine(todoScripts.Any(z => z.Name.EndsWith("T20200518T1023_InitialTestData.sql")));

            var result = upgrader.Build().PerformUpgrade();
```

As above, `GetScriptsToExecute` should return an empty array because all scripts have been run -- and are listed in the `SchemaVersions` table. But it's returning all scripts. Why?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the namespace of the `csproj` had changed and it is prepended to the script names in the `SchemaVersions` table which threfore did not match to the script names in the renamed project.

Comment: How did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I created a custom comparer for script names.

```
public class IgnorePrefixesComparer : IComparer<String>
{
    private readonly (string, string) _prefixes;

    public IgnorePrefixesComparer((string,string) prefixes)
    {
        _prefixes = prefixes;
    }
    public int Compare(string? a, string? b)
    {
        if (a is null || b is null) return StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Compare(a, b);

        RemovePrefix(ref a);
        RemovePrefix(ref b);
        return StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Compare(a, b);
    }

    private void RemovePrefix(ref string scriptName)
    {
        if (scriptName.StartsWithIgnoreCase(_prefixes.Item1)) scriptName = scriptName.Substring(_prefixes.Item1.Length);
        if (scriptName.StartsWithIgnoreCase(_prefixes.Item2)) scriptName = scriptName.Substring(_prefixes.Item2.Length);
    }
}
```

It's used like this:

```
var builder = DeployChanges.To
   .SqlDatabase(connectionString)
   .WithScriptsEmbeddedInAssembly(assemblyWithScripts)
   .LogToAutodetectedLog();

builder.Configure(c =>
{
    var customComparer = new IgnorePrefixesComparer(("OldPrefix", "NewPrefix"));
    c.ScriptNameComparer = new ScriptNameComparer(customComparer);
});

var result = builder.Build().PerformUpgrade();
```